# Connection timed out Error code 522 In Mac yosemite after migrating to Cloudflare

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

Im getting 522 in one of the devices for the specific domain and it is showing SSL certificate issue.

[image]

This is happening after migration to Cloudflare from Cloudfront. This is specific to a device (MacOS Yosemit v10.10.5) and is working fine in all other systems.
I tried all basic troubleshooting steps in clients end like clearing cache, resetting browser history and even tried on Safari. This seems to happen regardless of the browser.
I also tried from mobile device by connecting to the same wifi, to my surprise it was working there.
As far as I can understand from related forums, this would be caused due to cloudflare settings, probably the SSL settings being set to strict or something related.

How can I solve this issue? Any insights to this would be really helpful.